# Hadoop getting file not found exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying a run a sample program with single node hadoop cluster.
I'm getting an exception when I'm running a sample program (jar file).

I configured `core-site.xml` as localhost:9000. I put my text files in to HDFS properly and it can be view executing `hadoop dfs -ls /tmp` command.

Thanks.

> 13/11/27 05:47:52 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
>   13/11/27 05:47:52 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local617545423_0001
>   java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50090_secondary_**_y6aanv (Is a directory)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50090_secondary_**_y6aanv (Is a directory)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$TrackingFileInputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:71)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:107)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:182)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:126)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:427)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:75)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueLineRecordReader.initialize(KeyValueLineRecordReader.java:65)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:521)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>   13/11/27 05:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 35% reduce 0%

Comment: Could you please show me your code?

Comment: Here is the code exactly i'm trying. http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-basics-creating

Comment: Can you try the same code by putting your file in **/** or **/user** directory in HDFS ?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now. see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directories can not be in the input path directory for job even in the linux file system.

above `tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50090_secondary__y6aanv (Is a directory) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50090_secondary__y6aanv`

`Jetty_0_0_0_0_50090_secondary__y6aanv` is a directory which is in the Input path directory.

I changed the Input path and it is working now.